# Google Gae : Unreachable robots.txt

Tags: google-app-engine, seo, google-search-console

I have uploaded robots.txt in my url `http://watchmariyaanmovieonline.appspot.com/robots.txt` , But when i use google webmaster and do Fetch as google for my home page `http://watchmariyaanmovieonline.appspot.com/` i get error **Unreachable robots.txt**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `robots.txt` contents have one empty `Disallow` due to which you get that error.

```
 User-agent: * 
 Disallow:  
 Disallow: /cgi-bin/ 
 Sitemap: http://watchmariyaanmovieonline.appspot.com/sitemap.xml
```

Update it to:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Sitemap: http://watchmariyaanmovieonline.appspot.com/sitemap.xml
```

And it should work just fine, let me know if this helps :)